# How to add and remove Firebase db trigger as part of another db trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've got a small firebase app where I'd like to add a change listener (Db Trigger) when another change happens (e.g. particular property has changed it's value to 'listen') and then remove it when that 'trigger value' changes again. Is it possible?

```
exports.liveLessonPracticeMonitor = functions.database.ref('/some/property/path')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        if (!change.before.exists() && change.after.val() === 'listen') {

            // Can I do it here ?

            // start another listener. 
            functions.database.ref('/some/other/property/path')
                .onWrite((otherChange, otherContext) => {
                    // my code
                }
        } else if (change.before.val() === 'listen' && change.after.val() === 'stop') {
            // stop listening what I've subscribed to two lines above

            // How to do that?
        }

        return null
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Triggers can't be added or removed programmatically.  They must be exported from index.js and deployed using the Firebase CLI.

Comment: This is what I found too, but there was hope that it is me missing something rather than it's being truth

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible but if you are trying to do something based on input you get, you can always add `if-else` statement to do so. And if you just don't want to do anything you can add a `console.log('Invalid Input')` in the last else part. So the actual trigger is just logging a statement than doing anything else...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately if/else is not enough. Change in one property supposed to be a trigger to start listening changes in another, but looks like it is not possible ATM

Comment: @Grigori Can you provide me any example of what input you get and what you want to do with that. I might help better.

Comment: Sure, here we go. Context - learning/courses/lessons. I'd like know when a particular lesson has started (state has changed value to 'STARTED') and until it's been running I'd like to add another listener related to user activities on this lesson (e.g. user lesson practice status changes, which shows user's progress) so that once it changes, I can update the summary. When lesson has finished (state is 'FINISHED') - I don't need this activity listener any more. The code explaining it you can see in the main question. Is there anything particular you'd like me to elaborate in the question?